# django-registration - how do i change example.com in the email?

Tags: django, django-registration

I have the django-registration setup and it sends emails - yay!

However, it's decided that it would be ace to call my site "example.com", which is not the name I decided to use. Cool name, but not for me.

How do I change example.com to something else? I read somewhere that I go to the admin page but - spoiler alert - I've never used the admin page in django and am not actively planning on this currently (but maybe someday?)

So I go to the admin page - `/admin/sites/site/` - and sure enough I can see "example.com" and "domain name". But now what? I added my sites domain name and "display name", but how do I *select* to use it? I even deleted example.com!

However, the email insists on still sending out example.com. All the sites I read just  say "use admin", but I don't know if maybe my admin is broken (which would be odd, as I really haven't touched it) or if there is a link i'm missing?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The entry you saw originally on the `admin/sites/site/` page, with `example.com` and `domain name`, is the one you should simply edit for the quickest results (instead of adding a new Site object).

**What's really happening?**

In your settings file, Django automatically defines a `SITE_ID` property when you create your project, which is by default set to `1`. This points to the `example.com` Site you see in the admin. If you want to use the `Site` object you created, or change Site objects later when you need the functionality, you can change that `SITE_ID` property to the id of the `Site` object you created. Hope this helps!

Comment: ahhhhh. let me give that a whirl. i should have noted that after deleting example.com registration fails because the id "1" isn't in the db anymore. Silly me, and it all makes sense now with what you said~!

Comment: just to be clear - i fixed my problem by adding a new entry into the django_site table. The entry had an id of one, and then my domain and display name - phew! It now all works, brilliant and thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The site object in the template comes from the Django Site model. When you do a syncdb, it defaults automatically to example.com

If you login to Django's admin interface, you will find "Sites". Inside it, you will be able to change `example.com` to whatever you like. Just set the id of the site u want to use as current site in your `settings.py` as `SITE_ID = ID`.
e.g if you editted the `example.com` domain name to `mysite.com` and display name as `MYSITE`. then `SITE_ID = 1` because that is the only content we have in our "Sites" table and its `ID` is `1`. if like to add another "Sites" details leaving the `example.com` untouched, remember to set the `SITE_ID` to `ID` of the one u added

[image]